# How do I use patterns with convertNumber?

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to use the `f:convertNumber` tag.  I want to use multiple patterns.  I see you can do that with the date tag and the color tag.  Is there any way to do it with the `convertNumber` tag without creating a custom tag.

My problem is I want to be able to accept $ signs or no $ sign for my input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the dollar sign (if the number is a currencty), you can try:

```
<f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
```

And for any pattern you can:

```
<f:convertNumber pattern=".." />
```